# spring admin server ui : metrics and info end points are not mapping (returns 404)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I have a spring cloud services with the following spring package versions

```
<dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.SR4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

and I have my spring boot admin server ui running in 9003 port. I am using eureka discovery client to register my end points to the registry service.

My application.yml for the service is contains the following configurations.

```
server:
  context-path: /myservice
  port: 0

management:
  context-path: /mng
  security:
    enabled: false

eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true   
    statusPageUrlPath: ${server.context-path:}${management.context-path:}/info
    healthCheckUrlPath: ${server.context-path:}${management.context-path:}/health
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${EUREKA_DNS:localhost}:8761/eureka/
```

When I start my service I can see the following logs regarding my api endpoint

```
2018-01-11 16:01:22.176  INFO 6070 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mng/health || /mng/health.json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
2018-01-11 16:01:22.177  INFO 6070 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mng/info || /mng/info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-11 16:01:22.177  INFO 6070 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mng/mappings || /mng/mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-11 16:01:22.177  INFO 6070 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mng/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2018-01-11 16:01:22.178  INFO 6070 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mng/metrics || /mng/metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
```

when I start my dashboard following mapping info logs are printed

```
2018-01-11 22:04:00.886  INFO 55 --- [tp1976870338-18] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/c5a746b1/health/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController]
2018-01-11 22:04:00.886  INFO 55 --- [tp1976870338-18] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/c5a746b1/env/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController]
2018-01-11 22:04:00.886  INFO 55 --- [tp1976870338-18] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/c5a746b1/metrics/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController]
```

My problem now is when I open my dashboard Ui, its is trying to get the metrics info from "/api/applications/c5a746b1/metrics" but it returns 404 error. but in the browser when I type manually "/myservice/mng/metrics", I can see the metrics info.

I am newbee to the spring cloud , any help appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding the following configuration to my config file.       eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true   
    metadataMap:
        management: 
            context-path: ${server.context-path}${management.context-path}

Answer (score 0):

You should update to a 1.4.x and add a `mangament.context-path` entry to the services' metadata. This way the SBA server knows the correct path of your actuator endpoints.